# C++ method called from DLL returns data from previous call in Adobe Air native extension

Tags: c++, dll, air, air-native-extension

I am experiencing a weird problem .I wrote a native extension for Adobe Air app.
It is  C++ code compiled to DLL with VS2010 .I have a method to which I pass an array of numbers and then get an array of results.First time I call that method it return the correct array with correct data and length.But if I call that method in a row twice ,second time the array contains both -the data from the first call and from the second.It is as if the DLL would cache the data from the previous call.I clean everything up.Also all the variables are local and cleaned/destroyed once the method call finishes. May be my settings for DLL compilation are wrong as I am not C++ guru.
Thanks for help in advance.

UPDATE: 
I found the solution.It had to do with "extern 'C" " wrapper which I forgot to add to my C++ methods.

Comment: Need to see some code my friend. This could be any number of things. Try posting the methods where you call, your context initialization and the native method. Also post any code where you're accessing the AS3 class or any AS3 data from the native side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.It had to do with "extern 'C" " wrapper which I forgot to add to my C++ methods.